# Multiple join in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, join

Does anyone know how to use multiple join in CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
$Zonas = $this->Zona->find('all', array(
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'plantas',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                       'Zona.id = plantas.zona_id'  
                    )
                ),
                 array(
                    'table' => 'equipos_computo',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                       'plantas.id = equipos_computo.planta_id '  
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Associations

For ver 2.x

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

For ver 3.x

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html